# Вероятно, некоторые вопросы заслуживают переоткрытие

Tags: обсуждение, закрытие-вопросов, переоткрытие-вопросов

Собственно, это не вопрос, а объявление.

Comment: Серьезно? Объявление о чате для "открывашек"?

Comment: @DmitriySimushev, это объявление древнее вашего яата. Я толькго скрипт в ответ дописал. Сейчас и про ваш чат написал. Все довольны?

Comment: @Qwertiy сама по себе идея сомнительна - выглядит так, как будто вы предлагаете просто открывать вопросы, а не улучшать их перед открытием.

Comment: @Qwertiy, нет, не доволен. Тут дело не в том о каком это чате объявление, а в том, что сам вопрос попахивает офтопиком. Даже для меты

Comment: @Qwertiy, но это только мое мнение, которое я выражаю через минус и голос за закрытие

Comment: @DmitriySimushev, тут нет другой системы объявлений.

Comment: А где ещё располагать объявления о жизни сообщества?

Comment: @PashaPash: Вот и чат создан для обсуждения. Мы ведь все знаем, что перед _закрытием_ вопросов всегда проходит тщательное обсуждение, взвешиваются все за и против, выслушиваются голоса обеих сторон!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Чат для переоткрытия вопросов:

http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32012/

## Чат для закрытия вопросов:

http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32210/

## Как отправить уведомление всем в чате?

Следующий скрипт добавит кнопку `notify`, при нажатии которой, всем пользователям чата, которым можно послать уведомление, таковое будет отправлено:

```
document.getElementById('chat-buttons').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend',`<button class="button" id="notify-all-button" onclick="(()=>{var res = [];CHAT.RoomUsers.pingableUsersIncludeIncomplete().forEach(user => res.push('@'+user.name.replace(/\s/,'')));document.getElementById('input').value='/all: '+res.join(', ');document.getElementById('sayit-button').click()})()">notify</button>`)
```

Аналогичная версия для перечисления всех, чьи аватарки есть в верхнем углу. Полупрозрачные тоже участвуют:

```
document.getElementById('chat-buttons').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend',`<button class="button" id="notify-all-button" onclick="document.getElementById('input').value='/all: '+Array.prototype.map.call(document.querySelectorAll('#present-users img'),img=>'@'+img.title.replace(/\s/g,'')).join(', ');document.getElementById('sayit-button').click();">notify</button>`)
```

Comment: Для пользования надо (в хроме) нажать F12, перейти в закладку "консоль", скопировать туда и нажать `enter`

Comment: можно вставлять в адресную строку браузера. дописав `javascript://`

Answer (score 3):

Предлагаю отредактировать описание чата. С такого:

> Обсуждаем и переоткрываем вопросы, заслуживающие этого

На такое:

> Улучшаем и переоткрываем вопросы, заслуживающие этого

Стоит ли переоткрывать вопросы, не улучшая их?

Comment: Во-первых, некоторые - да. Во-вторых, а как менять описание чата?

Comment: @Qwertiy во вкладке [general](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/32012/?tab=general) есть кнопка «edit» рядом с названием для владельца комнаты.