# Закрытие вопросов с принятыми ответами

Tags: поддержка, закрытие-вопросов

Возможно я опять что-то пропустил, но возникает подозрение, что вопросы с "решением" нельзя помечать как вопросы к закрытию.

Ситуация: задается, к примеру, вопрос "Какой ваш любимы язык программирования?", который прямо противоречит разделу https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask
Некто, вполне возможно в сговоре с задающим вопрос, отвечает "Мой любимый язык - brainfuck" и его ответ тут же помечается как решение. Теперь имеется незакрываемый опросник с явно странным решением. Баг? Фича? Что было предложено делать в таких ситуациях, если было?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C [выходом из беты](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1985/%D0%9D%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D1%8D%D1%80%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8C-%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7-%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8B) ты потерял право закрывать вопросы.

[Набирай 3000](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions) - до этого ты никакие вопросы закрывать не сможешь.

Кстати, рядом [есть тематические чаты](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1839/%D0%92%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8B-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%82-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B5).

Comment: Все, понял проблему, спасибо за разъяснения! Значит, мимо прошло. Можете сносить вопрос, если он не к месту.

Comment: Как обычно, возражаю против тематических чатов. Для закрытия есть тематические очереди проверок, а для обсуждения — общий чат.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, очереди проверок имеют ограничения по давности и ещё какие-то.

Answer (score 2):

Закрывать можно все вопросы, как и прежде. Просто мы тут внезапно [из беты вышли](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1985/%d0%9d%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d1%8d%d1%80%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%89%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%8c-%d0%b1%d0%b5%d0%b7-%d0%b1%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%8b). Кроме прочего, это означает поднятие планки репутации для всех привилегий. В частности, сейчас [привилегия "Закрывать и переоткрывать вопросы"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions) требует 3000 репутации. Поэтому на данный момент вы лишились возможности закрывать вопросы вообще. Чтобы вернуть себе право, вам нужно заработать ещё немногим более 500 репутации.

Если у вас есть привилегия для закрытия, то закрывать вопрос вы не сможете по следующим причинам:

- на вопрос *объявлен конкурс* (ромбовый модератор может отменить конкурс, но это очень редкое исключение);
- вопрос *заблокирован* модератором (блокировку может поставить и снять только ромбовый модератор).

В остальных случаях препятствий для закрытия вопроса нет.

Что касается вопросов с принятыми ответами, то единственное, от чего защищает принятие ответа — это от *автоматического удаления* вопросов без ответов.

Answer (score 0):

Я могу голосовать за закрытие вопросов с принятыми ответами.
Да и вообще, такие периодически в очереди проверок попадаются.

Comment: Хм... Вот http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/473841/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8E-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%82-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-php и я не вижу "закрыть", вижу только "поделиться править тревога.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, там 2 голоса на закрытие висит.

Comment: Все ясно, рейтинга не хватает, ниже пояснили. У этого и в самом деле нет решения, у другого с решением была та же проблема.